# Unsupported package installation, the Arch Way

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation

### No AUR, no PKG.

I want to install [Bro](https://www.bro.org/), listed in Arch's "[List of applications](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/list_of_applications#Network_security)". But I can't find it in AUR, and it doesn't have a PKGBUILD file.

---

### To make, or to makepkg?

It does however have a Makefile, and a config shell-script. But after reading through them, I'm not convinced this is compatible with the Arch philosophy.

Is it recommended that I make a PKGBUILD, or is there another way to install it correctly? What is best practice?

---

### FYI:

I know that how to get it to work, more or less. I want to do this *the Arch Way*. Not to simply hack it together. I want to **really** learn how Linux works.

Comment: http://pkgbuild.com/git/aur-mirror.git/tree/bropages/PKGBUILD

Comment: The Bro Network Security Monitor. Not bro pages.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Should be more careful next time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to learn how Linux works, then you would typically install it from source with something like

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

If you want to do it the Arch way, make a `PKGBUILD` and share it on the `AUR`, so others don't have to go through the hassle of installing it from source. Your `PKGBUILD` will contain the same steps as if you install it from source. Hence it will contain something like

```
build(){
    cd "${pkgname}-${pkgver}"
    ./configure
    make
}

package(){
    cd "${pkgname}-${pkgver}"
    make DESTDIR="${pkgdir}" install
}
```

So in any way you want to install it from source first, to make sure it works. See the excellent [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PKGBUILD) for more information about the `PKGBUILD`.

Comment: Seems like a good solution. I'll see if I can help the community with that package. Thanks!

Comment: @Payne The disadvantage of the first way (manually running `make install`) is that it will install untracked files through your system, making uninstallation difficult. If you use a PKGBUILD, then the package manager knows about the installation, and it is trivial to uninstall/upgrade/etc. later.